# WPF TabItem Header Styling ONLY

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing a WPF application and trying to style the TabItem header ONLY to show a border with background color change when selected.  The problem is when I add that style it messes up the style for my TextBlock items in the TabItem.  I'm not a WPF / XAML expert.  Below is the style I'm using in my TabControl. I am also using MahApps metro stylings.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" Margin="2,0">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="10,2"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
```

Comment: You say "it messes up the style for my TextBlock items in the TabItem". Can you be more specific? I can't reproduce any TextBlock display issues with the XAML you provided.

Comment: With the styling in place it makes all my textblock items have a black foreground.  Which works fine when I use a white background but when I switch it to a black background you can't see the textblock items because the remain black instead of changing to white like my label items do.  If their was a way in the Style to just target the TabItem.Header element instead of the entire TabItem I think that would fix my issue, but I don't think you can do that, from my limited knowledge of XAML/WPF.

Comment: There's nothing in that XAML which could change anything's foreground color. Did you try setting `BasedOn` for the `Style`? `<Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">`

Comment: You ROCK!  That fixed my issues.  My textblock elements display correctly.  I'm not a XAML / WPF expert, I'd probably never found that solution.  Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a new style for a WPF control, if you're not totally reskinning everything, it's best to make it inherit from the existing implicit style. There's likely to be a lot of other stuff in there that you don't want to lose, and it looks like that's the case here. Try setting the `BasedOn` attribute like this, to the implicit `TabItem` style:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
```

And see if that helps.

In WPF, the [runtime `Type` of a control is conventionally used as the resource key for the style that's applied to it by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.defaultstylekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 2):

You can also define the style externally. This Style will help you to wrap the header content and align the header content to the center.

```
<Style x:Key="newTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
  <setter property="MaxWidth" value="150"/>
  <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate >
        <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"  TextAlignment="Center"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```